# ApexCharts chartOptions yaxis max and min bug

Tags: javascript, graphics, apexcharts

I'm working with ApexCharts and line charts. The problem is the following: I have limited the value of yaxis min:0 and max:20000 but the lines go outside the indicated ranges even so. I think the problem is with the plugin itself since it has a size limit up to the toolbar buttons and that is why the lines go outside the ranges. If anyone knows how to fix it or something on the subject I would appreciate it.

[image]

```
      chart: {
        toolbar: {
          show: true,
          tools:{
            download: false,
            pan: false,
            customIcons: [{
                icon: '<i class="q-icon notranslate material-icons cursor-pointer">settings</i>',
                index: 0,
                title: 'Configuración',
                click() {
                showPopup.value = true;
                },
            }],
          },
        },
      },
      legend: {
          show: false,
      },
      xaxis: {
          type: "datetime",
      },
      yaxis: {
          min: 0,
          max: 20000,
      }
```

I tried increasing and decreasing the min and max yaxis values ​​and the operation remained the same.